# How to Corvert .cer certificate into cert.pem and key.pem

Tags: python, server, openssl, opc-ua

Is it possible to convert a .cer file of P10 type (Basic256Sha256) into two files key.pem and cert.pem so that they are usable via server.set_security_string("Basic256Sha256, SignAndEncrypt, cert.pem, key.pem") in a Python opcua server? If so, can you tell me how?

Comment: No.  PKCS#10 (P10) is a request format, and does not contain the private key.

Comment: thank you,. But how can I set my cert.pem and key.pem in my server if I only have a .cer file?